# How do I unlock certain features based on user roles/permissions?

Tags: flutter

Good day,

I have an app idea that will require a login.  Different users will have different permissions.

For example base users will have access to tier 1. Manager users will have access to tier 1 and tier 2.  Dispatchers will have access to only tier 3.

Ideally, I would like the unusable tiers be hidden from users who don't have access to them but a "You don't have privileges to use this function" dialog would suffice.

Does anyone have a tutorial for this or Google search terms I could use to help me along?

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have tried. What language are you using?

Comment: Effectively upon successful login the server returns the permissions (can be included as part of the jwt if you have one). Store them in app state management and then for each screen that needs permission just look up if this user has it. Make sure that any API calls verifies permissions also